# How to fix right button border not showing in app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to make a game with multiple levels. My plan is to print 15 levels on 1 page. I have attached a [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqB0e.jpg) of the simple design I am currently using.

As you can see in the picture the right border of a button is not showing. For the parent I am using this java code:

```
LinearLayout horl = new LinearLayout(this);
horl.setId(worldVar);
horl.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
horl.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                      ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

And to set 3 buttons horizontally in this LinearLayout I use this code for the buttons. This code just has a simple for loop around to put 3 buttons in this LinearLayout:

```
Button button = new Button(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout
                                     .LayoutParams(getMarginInDp(100), getMarginInDp(100));

params.setMargins(getMarginInDp(1), getMarginInDp(25), getMarginInDp(1), 0);
button.setLayoutParams(params);
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
gd.setCornerRadius(5);
gd.setStroke(1, 0xFF000000);horl.addView(button);
```

The function getMarginInDp looks like this:

```
public int getMarginInDp(int dp){
    return (int) TypedValue
                .applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Does anybody have any idea how to make the border appear because I want to keep the buttons approximately this size and I may even slightly increase the margins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the weight to `0.33f` for each button:

```
Button button = new Button(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(getMarginInDp(100), getMarginInDp(100), 0.33f);
```

so they are distributed equally in the width of the layout.